# How to implement custom 'Use' and 'Retake' button in UIImagePicker?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a switched the cameracontrolls off, i mean

```
pickerCam.showsCameraControls=NO;
```

and i have custom capture button which does the capture functionality,

```
[pickerCam takePicture];
```

on click of this button the delegate will be called,

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)pi didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

Instead i need to implement custom 'Use' and 'Retake' option , how do i do that.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. In imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: Method save the image captured in a global varialbe
2. Add a view to overlay having Use and Retake Button,
3. In the Use target dismiss the picker.
4. In retake target remove the view having Use and Retake buttons.

Comment: don't forget to set picker.editing = false; to get didFinishedNotification directly after "takePicture"